# DataContentHandler cast exception sending email with Java

Tags: jakarta-mail, dotcloud

I am getting this exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: gnu.mail.handler.MultipartMixed cannot be cast to javax.activation.DataContentHandler` when sending an email from my *deployed* Dotcloud application (from my *local* machine it works fine). I previously used Spring's javamail, which did not work. Then I found [this suggestion](http://answers.dotcloud.com/question/334/java-mail-crashes) but still no success.

I am using Gmail SMTP. Configuration is done programmatically in my Java mail sender class. I also declared the same configuration parameters in the dotcloud.yml file.

I can't figure out what I am missing. Did someone have a similar problem? And how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to run your code using this alternate Java service (it's a re-implementation of dotCloud Java service using the custom API): https://github.com/jpetazzo/jetty-on-dotcloud

It gives much more flexibility, which means you should be able to disable the conflicting mail libraries. If you are willing to go that route, don't hesitate to get help from dotCloud's support!